# Port Unification in grpc-java

Tags: grpc, grpc-java

I am looking for an approach to enable SSL on demand for gRPC.

[Netty doc](https://netty.io/4.1/xref/io/netty/example/portunification/package-summary.html) shows this can be done by adding a custom *ByteToMessageDecoder* handler, reading through the initial bytes, and making decisions on the fly.

Does grpc-java support port unification? From my initial dig at the code, the [server-starter](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/netty/src/main/java/io/grpc/netty/NettyServer.java#L228) doesn't seem to expose any interface to inject custom handlers.

Comment: No, grpc-java does not support this. There's some way to do this for in-tree solutions, but the integration is deep and requires non-public APIs. With what do you want to port share?

Comment: @EricAnderson basically enable the gRPC server to accept TLS as well as non-TLS traffic on the same port.

Comment: That is a generic feature, so could be part of grpc-java itself. I'd suggest opening an issue for grpc-java and we can discuss the use-case there.

Comment: Opened a [feature request](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/9002) for the same